# Configure a configuration file to properly decode the desired barcodes using QuaggaJs

Tags: javascript, quaggajs

I am using QuaggaJs to decode barcodes for our book inventory system and it either doesn't scan or returns false positives many times.  The configuration setup is shown below

I have tried several revisions on my configuration for quagga and nothing seems to work.

this is the javascript configuration for my quagga configuration:

here:

```
 var liveStreamConfig = {
      inputStream: {
        type : "LiveStream",
        constraints: {
          width: {min: 640},
          height: {min: 480},
          aspectRatio: {min: 1, max: 100},
          facingMode: "environment" // or "user" for the front camera
        }
      },
      locator: {
        patchSize: "medium",
        halfSample: true
      },
      numOfWorkers: (navigator.hardwareConcurrency ? navigator.hardwareConcurrency : 4),
 decoder: {
      readers: ['ean_reader', 'code_128_reader', 'ean_8_reader', 'code_39_reader', 'code_39_vin_reader', 'codabar_reader', 'upc_reader', 'upc_e_reader', 'i2of5_reader']
 },

      locate: true
    };
```

the system can be demoed at https://apps.skuflow.com/freelancer/#/bfb using safari.

I need help with the following:

a) how can I get this returning accurate decodes for EAN, EAN-13, EAN-8, EAN-5, and EAN-2 barcodes.  Right now it just returns false positives and is causing a lot of inventory errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the way I fixed this is to simply scan multiple times (currently 3 times) and compare results. When all results are the same it means its accurate. Errors seem to only happen once most of the times.